# C memory deallocation?

Tags: c, malloc, free

I created a program for removing extra spaces from string.

```
void removeDuplicateSpaces(char **c){  //a-b---c
    char *a=*c;
    char *b=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(*c));  <-- allocation
    int i=0,nf=0,space=0;
    for(;a[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(a[i] != ' '){             //a-b-
            if(space>1){
                b[nf]=a[i];
                nf++;
                space=0;
            }else{
                b[nf]=a[i];
                nf++;
            }
        }else{
            space++;
            if(space==1 && i!=0){
                b[nf]=' ';
                nf++;
            }
        }
    }
    b[i]='\0';
    *c=b;
    }

int main(void) {
    char *a="    Arista    is     hiring    from   ISM   Dhanbad";
    removeDuplicateSpaces(&a); //function prototype can't be changed.
    printf("%s",a);     // ? where to deallocate.
    return 0;
}
```

[Working demo](http://ideone.com/geFH2w)

It is working fine. But the issue is where should i deallocate memory, allocated in `removeDuplicateSpaces()` function. If i add free statement after the `printf` in `main` then it make my program to crash(`signal 6 abort`). So what is the correct way ?

---

Original Problem

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char *foo = "    Arista    is     hiring    from   ISM   Dhanbad";
    void removeDuplicateSpaces(foo);
    printf("%s\n", foo);
}
```

Above code was given. Write a function `removeDuplicateSpaces` so as to remove the extra spaces in the given string.

For Example : ( ‘-’ denotes spaces for clarity)

```
Input String : (without quotes)
“—-Arista——is—-hiring—-from-ISM–Dhanbad”
Output String :
“Arista-is-hiring-from-ISM-Dhanbad”
```

Comment: The return value you *do* need to deallocate. The *original* pointer you do not. `free(a);` after you `printf()`, but before the `return` statement. And you should probably know that this function has undefined behavior. You only allocate space equivalent to the size of a pointer, not the original string. `char *b=malloc(sizeof(a));` allocates the size of a pointer, not the length of the input string.

Comment: I mean you need to fix the original function so it doesn't have undefined behavior *first*. And I already told you where to delicate the (incorrectly sized) malloced data: after the closing `printf()` but before the return, `free(a);`.

Comment: Changing it from `sizeof(a)` to `sizeof(*a)` isn't the solution. That will allocate space for **one** character rather than the space for the length of the string + 1 for the terminating zero. Do you know what a zero-terminated string in C is? How do you find its length ?

Comment: Still missing space for the terminating zero, and I hope you realize this function is prototyped rather poorly. It takes a pointer to a const-char-pointer. This means passing the address of a non-const char pointer is technically invalid, as it the inner const qualifier is removed. Further, you can't "fix" that by making `main()`s variable `a` const, because then you can't `free()` it without a hard cast. In short, the input parameter for this is typed *wrong*. I don't know what the original *problem* was that this function solves, but it smells like an XY problem to me. Good luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig Posted the actual problem. It was asked during the interview.

Comment: Your post of the original problem makes an *enormous* difference. The solution to this is simpler than you think. Note it does NOT take the *address* of a pointer for the parameter. it takes the original pointer only. there should be no dynamic allocation in this whatsoever. You should not the original problem assigns a read-only string literal to a non-const `char*`. While this make work for C89 and prior, C99 requires `foo` be declared as `char foo[] = ...` if you're going to be writing to the string (which you are for this problem).

Comment: Further, if thats the original question code *verbatim* it won't even compile This: `void removeDuplicateSpaces(foo);` isn't valid C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an alternative way to do it

```
char* removeDuplicateSpaces( char const * src )  // show that input string is read-only
{
  char* strnospaces = calloc( 1, strlen(src)+1 );// string is filled with \0's
  for (char *t = strnospaces, *s = src; *s; )    // copy until \0
    if (!isspace(*s)) *t++=*s++; else s++;       // copy only if not space
  return strnospaces;  
}
```

Comment: It was suggested by me during interview. But i'm not allowed to change the `void` return type. :(

Comment: ah ok! then i would suggest you use char [] as input instead of a pointer, that way it is more clear that you are modifying the string i.e. `void removeDuplicateSpaces( char src[] )`

Comment: if the input is in array format, will it modify the original string ? +1 i like the solution.

Comment: if you pass an array to the function you can modify it, you should not pass a pointer to a string literal if you are modifying the contents. a string literal is read-only. e.g. `char* p = "mytext";` otoh `char p[] = "mytext";` is not read-only

Answer (score 1):

It's better not to return some allocated string from your removeDuplicateSpaces function. Instead modify it to operate on already allocated buffer, then you will know exactly when memory you allocated can be freed.

Something like this:

```
char *a="    Arista    is     hiring    from   ISM   Dhanbad";
char *b = (char *)malloc(sizeof(a)); // for sure result string will be less or equal to origin
removeDuplicateSpaces(&a, b);
printf("%s",b);
free(b);
```

and in `removeDuplicateSpaces` you don't need to allocate anything then.

**EDIT:**
Try this

```
void removeDuplicateSpaces(const char **c){  //a-b---c
    char *a=*c;
    int i=0,nf=0,space=0;
    for(;a[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(a[i] != ' '){             //a-b-
            if(space>1){
                a[nf]=a[i];
                nf++;
                space=0;
            }else{
                a[nf]=a[i];
                nf++;
            }
        }else{
            space++;
            if(space==1 && i!=0){
                a[nf]=' ';
                nf++;
            }
        }
    }
    a[nf]='\0';
}

int main()
{
    char *a="    Arista    is     hiring    from   ISM   Dhanbad";
    char *b = (char *)malloc(strlen(a)+1);
    strcpy(b, a);
    removeDuplicateSpaces(&b); //function prototype can't be changed.
    printf("%s",b);
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Function prototype **cannot** be changed.

Comment: Then you have to modify your algorithm not to allocate new string but change existing one. It's just an array of chars and you can "compress" it by shifting values left and put '\0' at the new end.

Comment: Please provide the code. I can't think of it. I mean i don't know how to modify(if possible) literal strings.

Comment: why do you have `char *b = (char *)malloc(sizeof(a));`? Were you thinking about strlen(a) maybe ?

Comment: @cacho just copy-pasted it and didn't notice :) ty. WhozCraig pointed it out in comments to original post already.

Answer (score 0):

You would suggest the following solution. Make return type of your function to be `char*` which will return the allocated memory pointed by `b`. Then change invocation of the function like shown in the following updated code. You can `free` the memory in `main()` after `printf` then.

```
#include<stdio.h>

char *removeDuplicateSpaces(const char **c){  //a-b---c
    char *a=*c;
    char *b=malloc(sizeof(a));  <-- allocation
    int i=0,nf=0,space=0;
    for(;a[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(a[i] != ' '){             //a-b-
            if(space>1){
                b[nf]=a[i];
                nf++;
                space=0;
            }else{
                b[nf]=a[i];
                nf++;
            }
        }else{
            space++;
            if(space==1 && i!=0){
                b[nf]=' ';
                nf++;
            }
        }
    }
    b[i]='\0';
    *c=b;
    return b;
    }

int main(void) {
    char *a="    Arista    is     hiring    from   ISM   Dhanbad";
    char *c;
    c=removeDuplicateSpaces(&a);
    printf("%s",a);     // ? where to deallocate.a
    free(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Function prototype can't be changed.

Comment: @Arpit Per your posted update, the prototype *must* be changed (though not necessarily to conform to this answer) as the original problem requires a `char*`, and your function requires a `const char **`. they're completely different types and not compatible.